Let $R$ be a ring. Prove that there exists a unique ring morphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $R$.
I wrote a proof for this exercise but I am not sure it is right... I don't have access to any correction and I feel like it is missing something, would appreciate any advice. My specific concern is that I am not sure I can factor out the x when performing the operation in the ring R.
Let $f,g\colon\mathbb{Z}\to R$ be two group morphisms. Consider any $x\in\mathbb{Z}$. We have that
$$f(x) = f(\underbrace{1+\cdots+1}_{x\text{ times}}) = \underbrace{f(1)+_{R}\cdots+_{R}f(1)}_{x\text{ times}} = x\cdot_{R} f(1)$$and similarly, we obtain
$$g(x) = x\cdot_{R} g(1)$$
By properties of group morphisms, we have that, $f(1) = g(1) = 1_{R}$. Therefore,
$$x\cdot_{R} f(1) = x\cdot_{R} g(1) \implies f(x) = g(x) \;\;\;\forall x\in \mathbb{Z}$$
We have shown that $f = g$ so any group morphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $R$ is unique.
EDITED
Thank you! I am still not sure if it is right, but using what you said, my proof now looks like this:
Let $f:\mathbb{Z}\to R$ be a ring morphism. First, let us consider $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $n$ is nonnegative. By induction, we shall prove that $f(n) = n\cdot 1_{R} = \underbrace{1_{R} + ..+1_{R}}_{\text{n times}} = \sum_{j=1}^{n}{1_{R}}$
Since $f$ is a ring morphism, we have that $f(0) = 0_{R}$ and $f(1) = 1_{R}$, so the base case holds. Assume that $f(n) = n\cdot 1_{R}$. Then $f(n+1) = f(n) + f(1) = n\cdot 1_{R} + 1_{R} = (n+1)\cdot 1_{R}$ by distributivity of multiplication. Hence we have shown that $f(n) = n\cdot 1_{R}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
Now to prove the result for negative integers, let us consider the following: $0_{R} = f(0) = f(n + (-n)) = f(n) + f(-n) = n\cdot 1_{R} + f(-n) \implies f(-n) = -(n\cdot 1_{R})$ and by associativity of multiplication, $-(n\cdot 1_{R}) = n\cdot(-1_{R}) = f(-n)$.
Therefore, the only ring morphism from $\mathbb{Z}\to R$ is $n\mapsto n\cdot 1_{R}$.

You are confusing between group morphism and ring morphism. $R$ is not a group with respect to multiplication. The reason why $f(1)=1_R$ is because this is a homomorphism of rings. Also, I don't see where you showed that such a homomorphism exists.

Welcome to Math.SE. If $x$ is a natural number, the statement $f(x) = xf(1)$ can be proved by induction. No need for "factoring out $x$" (not sure what you mean by this). Is that what you're struggling with?

About the formatting: It looks like you have inserted a lot of text into math mode (between $$). The typesetting for math mode is quite different to what it is for text in a paragraph. The correct way to render math inside of a paragraph is to just put the formulae in single dollar signs, and have the text outside.

First of all, you use "group morphisms" instead of "ring morphisms", which is not right. Even other than that, there are a few problems.

For all $x\in\mathbb Z$,$$f(x) = f(\underbrace{1+\cdots+1}_{x\text{ times}}) = \underbrace{f(1)+_{R}\cdots+_{R}f(1)}_{x\text{ times}} = x\cdot_{R} f(1)$$

This has several problems. First thing, the "$x$ times" part does not make sense when $x\leq0$, so you need to work around that. Second thing, the sum $r+_R\cdots+_Rr$ ($x$ times) (you have taken $r=f(1)$) is not $x\cdot_Rr$, but rather $x_R\cdot r$ (where $2_R=1_R+_R1_R$ and so on). The expression $x\cdot_Rr$ does not make sense as $x$ is an integer, not an element of $R$ so you cannot multiply it with $r$.
(Note: Not sure how much rigour you want, but you may want to justify that $f(x_1+\cdots+x_n)=f(x_1)+\cdots+f(x_n)$, which is of course straightforward due to induction.)
After all of that, the proof goes through, but that still does not show that there is a unique ring morphism $\mathbb Z\to R$, as you only showed that there is at most one such morphism. You need to explicitly define at least one morphism and then you are done.
Hope this helps. :)

Hello! Thank you for the comment :) I completely agree and was off-put by writing $x\cdot_{R} 1_{R}$ since it does assume that $x\in R$ which it isn't necessarily... I have searched online for this proof and found here  https://mast.queensu.ca/~ggsmith/Math210/notes06.pdf that in problem 5.0.4, they also did the same thing (and I found the same on another website too). I don't feel that it is entirely right, but I am also not sure what else to do
